# Click button and go back to first one after first click

Tags: javascript, html

```
<html>
<head>
  <title>eLab</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function change() 
    {
      document.getElementById('myTable').style.height= "400";
      document.getElementById('myTable').style.width= "1000";
      return true;
    }
    </script>
</head>

<body>    
<table border="1" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="1" style="height:1000;width:400;" id="myTable" align=center>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <th>This is the head!</th>
            <th>I'm the head too!</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td align=center>Part 1</td>
            <td align=center>Part 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td align=center>Part 3</td>
            <td align=center>Part 4</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
      <td colspan="2" align=center> Part 5</td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>

<center>
  <input type="button" onclick="change()" value="Change It">
</center>

</body>
</html>
```

This is my html code.

After clicking the button, the table will change the height and width size.

I want to do this: after changing the size, if user clicks the button again, the table will change back to its original size or maybe it can change the size again as its original size.

Thank you!

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/RachGal/y01zr2mp/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you accept `css` involved, you can use toggle to toggle certain class to achieve that.

And from, [css length](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/length),  `1000` is not a valid `css` value, you should use something like `'1000px'`, otherwise the `width/height` would take no effect.

```css
#myTable.changed {
  width: 500px;
  height: 300px;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
  <title>eLab</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function change() 
    {
      document.getElementById('myTable').classList.toggle('changed');
      return true;
    }
    </script>
</head>

<body>    
 <!-- Note that the style you give here would not have an effect, as `height:1000` or `width:400` are not valid css length -->
<table border="1" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="1" style="height:1000;width:400;" id="myTable" align=center>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <th>This is the head!</th>
            <th>I'm the head too!</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td align=center>Part 1</td>
            <td align=center>Part 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td align=center>Part 3</td>
            <td align=center>Part 4</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
      <td colspan="2" align=center> Part 5</td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>

<center>
  <input type="button" onclick="change()" value="Change It">
</center>

</body>
</html>
```

And if `css` is not in concern, then you can just use a flag to decide the behavior of that function, [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0xy2mt0f/)

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var changeFlag = false;
    function change() {
      var table = document.getElementById('myTable');
      changeFlag = !changeFlag;
      var width, height;
      if (changeFlag) {  // Click in odd, then change to new w/h
          width = '500px';
          height = '600px';
      } else {   // Click in even, change to origin size.
          width = '400px';
          height = '1000px';
      }
      table.style.width = width;
      table.style.height = height;
      return true;
    }
    </script>
```

Comment: note that center is an obsolete tag as is align. to align text to center, OP should use td{text-align:center;} and to center a div OP should use margin-left and margin-right

Answer (score 0):

```html
<html>
<head>
  <title>eLab</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function change() 
    {
      if(document.getElementById('myTable').style.height == "400px") {
        document.getElementById('myTable').style.height= "1000";
        document.getElementById('myTable').style.width= "400";
      }
      else {
        document.getElementById('myTable').style.height= "400";
        document.getElementById('myTable').style.width= "1000";
      }
   
      return true;
    }
    </script>
</head>

<body>    
<table border="1" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="1" style="height:1000;width:400;" id="myTable" align=center>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <th>This is the head!</th>
            <th>I'm the head too!</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td align=center>Part 1</td>
            <td align=center>Part 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td align=center>Part 3</td>
            <td align=center>Part 4</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
      <td colspan="2" align=center> Part 5</td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>

<center>
  <input type="button" onclick="change()" value="Change It">
</center>

</body>
</html>
```

I changed change function to work with your purpose.
Let you check this code

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
<html>
<head>
  <title>eLab</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var isToggled = false;
    function toggleSize() 
    {
      if(!isToggled)
      {
        document.getElementById('myTable').style.height= "400";
        document.getElementById('myTable').style.width= "1000";
        isToggled = true;
      }
      else
      {
        document.getElementById('myTable').style.height= "900";
        document.getElementById('myTable').style.width= "400";
        isToggled = false;
      }
      return true;
    }
    </script>
</head>

<body>    
<table border="1" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="1" style="height:1000;width:400;" id="myTable" align=center>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <th>This is the head!</th>
            <th>I'm the head too!</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td align=center>Part 1</td>
            <td align=center>Part 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td align=center>Part 3</td>
            <td align=center>Part 4</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
      <td colspan="2" align=center> Part 5</td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>

<center>
  <input type="button" onclick="toggleSize()" value="Change It">
</center>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```css
.myTable1 {
  height : 1000px;
  width : 400px; 
}


.myTable2 {
  height : 400px;
  width : 10000px; 
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
<head>
  <title>eLab</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
          function change(){
              $('#myTable').toggleClass("myTable1");
              $('#myTable').toggleClass("myTable2");
            }
    </script>
</head>

<body>    
<table border="1" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="1" id="myTable" align="center" class="myTable1">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <th>This is the head!</th>
            <th>I'm the head too!</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td align=center>Part 1</td>
            <td align=center>Part 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td align=center>Part 3</td>
            <td align=center>Part 4</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
      <td colspan="2" align=center> Part 5</td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>

<center>
  <input type="button" onclick="change()" value="Change It">
</center>

</body>
</html>
```